# Cannot Write To Mage Log In 1.8

Tags: module, ce-1.8.1.0, log

I'm developing a module on a vanilla install of CE 1.8.1.0. I'm trying to write to a custom log file inside the module's observer. The log file is *created* but remains *empty* no matter what. Here's my code:

**app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml**:

```
<config>
    <global>
        ...
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <my_module>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>observeSummin</method>
                    </my_module>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And the Observer:

**app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php**:

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function observeSummin( $observer ) {
        if ( !$this->_isEnabled ) {
            Mage::log( 'is-enabled, 1: ', 'no', 'my_module.log', true );
            return;
        }

        Mage::log( 'is-enabled, 1: ', 'yes', 'my_module.log', true );

        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

        if ( $this->cartQualifies() ) {
            if ( $quoteItem ) {
                Mage::log( 'cart-qualifies, 1: ', 'yes', 'my_module.log', true );
            }
        } else {
            Mage::log( 'cart-qualifies, 1: ', 'no', 'my_module.log', true );
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've just dumped loads of log instances to catch any conditions. Apart from the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event, I've also tried hooking into the `sales_quote_add_item` and `checkout_cart_save_after` events, with the same results.

If I introduce an intentional code error in the observer, the error log catches it, otherwise, there are none. I've also tried to use `Mage::log` without the file parameter, but nothing is written to `system.log`.

The entire `var/` folder is `chmod 777` and logging is enabled in system config.

I'm lost as to why it's not logging - other Magento events are being logged in `system` and `exception`. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you enable from backend ?

Comment: @KeyulShah The `boolean true` as the fourth param overrides configuration setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to concatenate the first two arguments (`.` instead of `,`)? In any event, your second argument is being filtered out by the `Zend_Log` component.

Look at the `Mage::log()` definition:

```
public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
{
    //snip...
    $level  = is_null($level) ? Zend_Log::DEBUG : $level;
    //snip...
}
```

According to this use of `Zend_Log`, your second argument need to be an integer between 0 and 7; best to use the constants though:

```
class Zend_Log
{
    const EMERG   = 0;  // Emergency: system is unusable
    const ALERT   = 1;  // Alert: action must be taken immediately
    const CRIT    = 2;  // Critical: critical conditions
    const ERR     = 3;  // Error: error conditions
    const WARN    = 4;  // Warning: warning conditions
    const NOTICE  = 5;  // Notice: normal but significant condition
    const INFO    = 6;  // Informational: informational messages
    const DEBUG   = 7;  // Debug: debug messages
    //snip...
}
```

Comment: (*slaps forehead*) Thx Ben, this is working: `Mage::log( 'cart-qualifies: ', null, 'my_module.log', true );`